# Set database options in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core 3.1 with Model-First migrations. If the database doesn't exist, then it automatically creates one.

I need to enable SQL Server change tracking (NOT EF Core change tracking) on a table, but to do so, SQL Server Database Change tracking needs to be turned on. How would I set a database level option such as below in code?

```
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)
```

Answer (score 0):

- your can use raw sql

```
    using(var context = new SampleContext())
    {
        var commandText = "INSERT Categories (CategoryName) VALUES (@CategoryName)";
        var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test");
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, name);
    }
```

- or execute sql when migration

```
public partial class UpdateDbOptions: Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        var sp = @"ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase]  
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)";

        migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had it being output in the migration, but wondered if there was an explicit seam available for database level options that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @razaross444 If you wonder db is affected by migration, you could use first method.